# CPU js Function Call infinit Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I have an interesting question.
Here is my devtools screen shot:

[image]

As you see in Main(red arrow) there is a Function Call and it goes to infinite.
The code that call it is extremely simple:

```
                        <select
                      onChange={this.handleSelectScript}
                      className={`campaign-select-script
                      ${this.state.errors.script ? 'input-error' : ''}`}
                      value={this.state.data.selectedScript.id}
                    >

                      <option value="" disabled>
                        Выберите скрипт
                      </option>

                      {this.state.initialScripts
                        .filter(script => script.status === 'P')
                        .map(script => (
                          <option
                            key={script.script_uuid}
                            defaultValue={script.script_uuid === this.state.data.selectedScript.script_uuid}
                            value={script.script_uuid}
                          >
                            {script.title}
                          </option>
                        ))}

                    </select>
```

I tried a lot, I delete .filter() - result is the same.
The .map() call this infinite listeners in browser.

So I have no idea about this bug.

Comment: It looks like a bug in Chrome DevTools. You can file bug reports at https://crbug.com.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a bug, because I've tried in several Chrome versions, and I've change OnChange method to onSelect method - result is the same.

Comment: I’m the DevTool technical writer. I’m pretty sure it’s a bug. The “Function Call” item should never be longer than the “Event (mouseup)” item above it. In order to fix this bug, the DevTools team will need a running page where they can reproduce it.